How to insert values for the second time in a particular column in mysql?
I am trying to put values in a particular column with the help of insert into but I get some error, and when I am using "insert ignore into", then in output an extra observation in created where every other value is null and one value is add in the column in which I used insert into.
I was trying to put the values in that particular column

Use UPDATE statement

inserting twice is fine as long as you don't upset any indexes and event then it could be fine if you insert..on duplicate key..update to clarify what you want publish sample data, desired outcome and table definition as text.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

UPDATE table_name
SET column_name=new_value
WHERE condition;

Replace 'table_name' with the name of your table,
'column_name' with the column in which you want to update the rows/records,
'new_value' with the value you want to insert into the column,
'condition' specifies which rows need to be updated.
Example:
Updating single value of a specific row:
UPDATE students
SET grade='A'
WHERE id=123;

Updating multiple values of a specific row
UPDATE employees
SET salary = 50000, department = 'IT'
WHERE id = 123;

